# why do I get these weird stripes or waves in the background?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, lighting, artifacts

[image][image: I get these stripes or waves in the background, is it the sample size, I am using 300. blender 2.93, cycles, point light. sorry, I don't know if there is a term for this. and I rendered this in concierge render]

I get these stripes or waves in the background, is it the sample size, I am using 300.
blender 2.93, cycles, point light. sorry, I don't know if there is a term for this. and I rendered this in concierge render

Comment: Banding like that usually happens when trying to represent a subtle gradient using 8-bit instead of 16-bit. Are you using an image texture for the background, perhaps a .jpg? If not, what bit type are you using for your output?

Comment: if Christophers comment doesn't help, please provide blend file so we can check it out

Comment: mine Is at 8, I will try it at 16 and see if it's fixed

Comment: I didn't notice any banding while rendering a single frame even in 8bit and background is just white material, is it conversion to video that's causing the issue?

Comment: here's my blend project https://drive.google.com/file/d/12PDAA_GFEmQTWhkjtENdOsP5m2aQqYWd/view?usp=sharing